# Unable to import HTMLConverter

Tags: java, pdf, intellij-idea, itext, itext7

I have an existing Java project in which I need to create a PDF. I need HTMLConvertor to convert HTML to PDF and then use PDFReader and PDFStamper to add contents to the various fields(getAcroFields).

So I using iText 5.5.12 and I am unable to import HTMLConverter. 
Is it not supported for this version? 
I couldn't find documentation regarding the releases.
I tried the following but didn't work. I tried to add iText 7 as a new Library from Maven but versions until 5.5.12 are available.

I am new to Intellij, so how can I install iText, the version that supports HTMLConverter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You write:

> I tried to add iText 7 as a new Library from Maven but versions until 5.5.12 are available.

That is wrong. See installation instructions on the iText website: https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/Java

Copy-paste for in your POM file:

```
<dependencies>

    <!-- always needed -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- always needed -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>io</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- always needed -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- only needed for forms -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- only needed for PDF/A -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfa</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- only needed for digital signatures -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>sign</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- only needed for barcodes -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>barcodes</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- only needed for Asian fonts -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>font-asian</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- only needed for hyphenation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>hyph</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

To be able to use the pdfHTML add-on, you need to add this:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>itext</id>
    <name>iText Repository - releases</name>
    <url>https://repo.itextsupport.com/releases</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

This is temporary because for the moment pdfHTML is closed-source and not on Maven Central, but it will become open source soon enough, in the next couple of weeks.

You will need a license key for pdfHTML, either a 30 day trial or purchased, and then you add this to your POM:

```
<dependencies>


  <!-- pdfHTML -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- iText 7 License Key Library -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext-licensekey</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
  </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 3):

The `HtmlConverter` class is an add-on to iText 7. It doesn't work with iText 5. As a matter of fact, iText was rewritten from scratch to make `HtmlConverter` possible. See the [introduction to the HTML to PDF tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml) for a historical overview:

> In 2016, we released iText 7, a brand new version of iText that was no
>   longer compatible with previous versions, but that was created with
>   pdfHTML in mind. A lot of work was spent on the new Renderer
>   framework. When a document is created with iText 7, a tree of
>   renderers and their child-renderers is built. The layout is created by
>   traversing that tree, an approach that is much better suited when
>   dealing with HTML to PDF conversion. The iText objects were completely
>   redesigned to better match HTML tags and to allow setting styles "the
>   CSS way."

You can download iText 7 by following the download instructions: [iText 7 for Java](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/Java)

As for [pdfHTML](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfHTML), the first versions were developed in closed source after a long debate about the fact that too many third party developers weren't loyal to the iText developers. They pretended not to know that you typically can't use AGPL software for free in an application that is distributed (either as a binary or in a SaaS context) as closed source software. It was decided to make some add-ons closed source to create awareness, and to avoid that we had to sue (see slide 8 to 62 in [this presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/iTextPDF/ianal-what-developers-should-know-about-ip-and-legal)).

In the meantime, we've received approval to make pdfHTML open source (AGPL), but it will take a couple of weeks before the new release is done. In the meantime, you can register to get a [30-day trial](http://pages.itextpdf.com/iText-7-Free-Trial-Landing-Page-1.html) before you buy a license.

Comment: Is there any other way I can read a HTML template, add values to fields and render the PDF?
Can I use XMLWorkerHelper?
This sage answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35921388/how-to-convert-an-html-string-to-a-pdf-inputstream
suggests a way. 

Please help, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: See the [history](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml). You can use XML Worker, but (1.) it's not as complete as pdfHTML, (2.) you want get support for it (and it seems you *need* support), and (3.) it's also released as AGPL, so you might need a commercial license anyway if you use it in a commercial context. Since you are *new* at iText, why would you deliberately choose to use an old version??? That doesn't make much sense, does it?